# Print statements keep printing out multiple times instead of just once?

Tags: c, for-loop, printf

Here is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char names[2048][32];
    int removed[2048];

    int game;
    int n;

    int m;
    int k;
    int l;

    int i;
    int j;
    int round;
    int pos;

    int lowest;
    int next;

    // Read the number of games to be played
    scanf("%d",&n);

    // Process each game
    for(game = 1; game <= n; game++)
    {

        // Read the number of friends
        scanf("%d",&m);

        // Read the names of each friend
        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            scanf("%s",names[i]);

            // Mark the friend as having not been eliminated
            removed[i] = 0;
        }

        // Read the number of rounds and the number of "Ducks"
        scanf("%d %d", &k,&l);

        // If the number of rounds is greater than the number of friends
        // Jimmy will boot all his friends
        if(k >= m)
        {
            printf("Jimmy has friends no more.\n\n");
            continue;
        }

        // Simulate the game round by round
        pos = 0;
        for(round=0;round<k;round++)
        {
            // Walk around the circle stopping at the lth remaining friend
            for(i=0; i<=l; pos = (pos+1)%m)
            {
                if(!removed[pos])
                    i++;

                if(i == l+1)
                    // Give the friend we stopped at the boot
                    removed[pos]=1;

            }
        }

        lowest = 0;
        // Loop for each remaining friend
        for(i=0;i<(m-k);i++)
        {
            // Find the lowest numbered remaining friend
            while(removed[lowest])
                lowest++;

            // Find the friend with the first name alphabetically
            next = lowest;
            for(j=lowest;j<m;j++)
            {
                if(!removed[j] && strcmp(names[j],names[next]) < 0)
                    next = j;
            }

            // Print the name of the next friend and remove him/her from the circle
            removed[next] = 1;
            printf("Game %d:\n", game);
            printf("%s\n", names[next]);
        }
        printf("\n");


    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is what it inputs and outputs:

```
Input:
2
3
Bob
Cody
John
2 2
Game 1: (the output)
Cody(the output)

8
Carol
Casey
Nick
Kirsten
Ben
Bo
Billy
Heather
3 4
Game 2: (The output)
Billy(The output)
Game 2:(The output)
Bo(The output)
Game 2:(The output)
Carol(The output)
Game 2:(The output)
Kirsten(The output)
Game 2:(The output)
Nick(The output)
```

How can I have the "Game 2:" printf statement only show up once? I've tried putting it in different parts of the code but I still haven't gotten it. For better understanding of what I'm trying to get, here is what I'm trying to do:

```
Output:
Game 1:
Cody
Game 2:
Billy
Bo
Carol
Kirsten
Nick
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger - various useful tool for these situations.

Answer (score 1):

Move the printing of "Game" to outside of your `for` loop:

```
    // print "Game" here
    printf("Game %d:\n", game);
    // Loop for each remaining friend
    for(i=0;i<(m-k);i++)
    {
        // Find the lowest numbered remaining friend
        while(removed[lowest])
            lowest++;

        // Find the friend with the first name alphabetically
        next = lowest;
        for(j=lowest;j<m;j++)
        {
            if(!removed[j] && strcmp(names[j],names[next]) < 0)
                next = j;
        }

        // Print the name of the next friend and remove him/her from the circle
        removed[next] = 1;
        // print "game" was here
        printf("%s\n", names[next]);
    }
```